# SQL how to outer join first matching value without using nested subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join

So I have been having this problem for a while now, i need to join two tables, but I don't have a unique identifier so i have to use ID and date ranges instead. And if 2 date ranges overlap, i need to join first value. AND I need to be an outer join. The code i have right now is theoretically correct, but it doesn't fit the situation (I can't make this join an outer join, because I get an error this way).

The logic is following: Employee can be an Expatriate. If he is an expatriate, I need to show all columns. BUT the tricky part - if during the assignment (between effective_start_date and effective_end_date) he was in 2 different countries, I need to show information about the last trip only.
The last part (about only joining on MAX(valid_to needs to be adjusted)) - so this way, there is a unique combination of assignment_id, effetive_start_date, effective_end date (so this table joins to other tables correctly).

I know this can be fixed with a single join, I just can't figure out how (I can probably do it without using any nested subqueries).

Please, provide me with ORACLE syntax, yes I know some say it's outdated, but this piece of code absolutely needs to be in syntax its written in now + it's much more easy for me to understand.

```
with assignments (assignment_id, person_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date) as (
   select 456, 123, date '2015-01-01', date '2015-03-15' from dual union all  
   select 456, 123, date '2015-03-16', date '4712-12-31' from dual union all   
   select  975, 123, date '2015-03-16', date '4712-12-31' from dual union all
  select  674, 145, date '2015-03-16', date '4712-12-31' from dual
 ),


expatriates (person_id, home_country, host_country, date_from, date_to, valid_from, valid_to)
as
(
   select 123, 'TEST2', 'TEST2',    date '2015-01-01', date '2015-03-15', date '2015-01-01', date   '2015-03-15' from dual union all
   select 123, 'TEST1', 'TEST1',    date '2015-04-16', date '2016-06-15', date '2015-04-16', date   '2016-06-15' from dual union all
   select 123, 'TEST',  'TEST',   date '2015-03-16', date '2016-04-15', date '2015-03-16', date '2015-04-15' from dual

)

select 
a.assignment_id,
a.person_id, 
a.effective_start_date, 
a.effective_end_date,
subq.home_country, 
subq.host_country, 
subq.date_from, 
subq.date_to
from assignments a, expatriates subq 
where 
a.person_id=subq.person_id(+)
and subq.valid_from(+) <= a.effective_end_date
and subq.valid_to(+) >= a.effective_start_date
and subq.date_from(+) = 
(
  select 
    max(date_from) 
  from expatriates sq2 
    where 
      sq2.person_id = a.person_id and 
      sq2.valid_from <= a.effective_end_date and 
      sq2.valid_to >= a.effective_start_date 
)
```

Comment: Using a proper `left join` operator is also "Oracle syntax" - even Oracle suggests to stop using the old `(+)` operator.

Comment: Are you saying that the query you presented gives the correct results, but you want an alternative that does not use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Your query selects only expatriate date ranges that fall completely within an assignment period.  Do you need to also account for cases where the ranges overlap, but the assignment range does not completely contain the expatriate range?

Comment: There can be a case  where the ranges overlap, but the assignment range does not completely contain the expatriate range. Query i provided does not work if i outer join. Basicly it gives me everything i need, just doesn't work with outer join on the subquery.

Comment: You asked similar questions before and got solutions using ROW_NUMBER/RANK, you can apply it here, too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your concern with the starting query is that it uses a *correlated* subquery, and that is indeed a performance concern relative to an uncorrelated one.  The query can indeed be structured to avoid correlated subqueries, but not to more generally avoid a separate query for identifying which expatriate row associated with each assignment is the one to report upon.  The version below is pretty efficient, as the topmost query just filters unwanted rows from the CTE results.

That separate query can be structured as an inline view or as a common table expression.  Sticking in this regard to the letter of the question, I use a CTE below to avoid query nesting, even though there is a completely equivalent expression in terms of an inline view.  It uses standard outer join syntax.  It also uses the window function version of `MAX()`, which requires fairly recent Oracle.

```
with 
-- other CTEs ... ,
all_rows (assignment_id, person_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date,
  home_country, host_country, date_from, date_to, max_from) as
(
  select 
    a.assignment_id,
    a.person_id, 
    a.effective_start_date, 
    a.effective_end_date,
    subq.home_country, 
    subq.host_country, 
    subq.date_from, 
    subq.date_to,
    max(subq.date_from) over (partition by a.assignment_id, a.person_id)
  from
    assignments a
    left outer join expatriates subq
      ON a.person_id = subq.person_id
        and subq.valid_from <= a.effective_end_date
        and subq.valid_to >= a.effective_start_date
)
select *
from all_rows
where date_from = max_from or max_from is null
;
```

When combined with the CTEs you provided in the question, that query produces three result rows, each with a distinct combination of `assignment_id` and `person_id`.

To handle the case where the expatriate range overlaps the assignment range, but is not wholly contained within it, you might want to change the join condition to ...

```
      ON a.person_id = subq.person_id
        AND (subq.valid_from BETWEEN a.effective_start_date AND a.effective_end_date
          OR a.effective_start_date BETWEEN subq.valid_from AND subq.valid_to)
```

That covers all cases where the two ranges overlap.